# JQuery - Problem with mouseover

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I have the following scenario...

When I hover over **span.share-this**, it triggers a div called '*under*' to come into view. This bit works exactly the way I want. Now I set it so, that when the mouse cursor is on the *'under'* div and I mouseout, the *'under'* div goes away and everything is back the way it was (Everything is still dandy).

My problem is that when I hover over the **span.share-this** and do not navigate to the *'under'* div, but navigate away to another part of the page, the *'under'* div is still visible.

I would like to set it so, that if I navigate from **span.share-this** to another part of the page, the *'under'* div hides.

Does anybody know what function I should look at?

**JQuery Code**

```
$('#slider span.share-this').mouseover(function()
{   
    $(this).parents('li').children('div.under').css('bottom', '12px');
});

$('#slider div.under').mouseout(function()
{
    $(this).css('bottom', '52px');
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<li>
    <div class="item">
        <span class="share-this">Share This</span>
    </div>
    <div class="under">
        Under
    </div>
</li>
```

Testing url: http://www.eirestudio.net/share/

Comment: It works as intended for me (Chrome 4).

Comment: Just checked there in chrome. It doesn't. Hover over 'Share This' in the blue panel under where it say 'Save Money. Get Hottest Freebies Now!' No hover up an inch. The under div with social media icons is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a good start. You just need to add a few more mouseover's and mouseout's. Using hover will probably be the easiest.

```
$('#slider span.share-this').hover(function()
{   
    $(this).parents('li').children('div.under').css('bottom', '12px');
}, function(){
    $(this).parents('li').children('div.under').css('bottom', '52px');
});

$('#slider div.under').hover(function()
{
    $(this).css('bottom', '12px');
},function()
{
    $(this).css('bottom', '52px');
});
```

Depending on your needs and how far away, spacially, on the page, the two elements are, you may also want to look into `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` Javascript functions. If the span and the div are far enough away where someone could drag off of the `span.share-this` and not be mousing over the `div.under`, you would set a timeout which, after a certain number of milliseconds, would hide the `div.under`. And then if they are over the `div.under` you'd clear the timeout. Just quickly, it may resemble something like this:

```
function hideUnder(){
   $('#slider div.under').css('bottom', '52px');
}

var under;
$('#slider span.share-this').hover(function()
{   
    clearTimeout(under);
    $(this).parents('li').children('div.under').css('bottom', '12px');
}, function(){
    under = setTimeout(hideUnder, .5*1000);
});

$('#slider div.under').hover(function()
{
    clearTimeout(under);
    $(this).css('bottom', '12px');
},function()
{
    under = setTimeout(hideUnder, .5*1000);
});
```

Of course, though, this would cause a half-second delay before the `div.under` was hidden.

Comment: Thanks so much Munch! - It is 99% the way I want. I do get a slight flicker when I hover to the under div. (Extremelly slight!) I have tried to play around with the .5*1000 but I still get the flicker. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited the code, took out the mouseout effects that set the css bottom property and just rely on the timeouts that do that for you. Then that property isn't set twice. It was a slight error in my logic. Btw, `1000` is equivalent to 1 second. So you can change the timing accordingly. Try it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Munch, you are an absolute star! - You have no idea how much I appreciate your help. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

... me thinks you need to call .mouseout() on the share-this div and hide what what you want hidden there. Or I missed something :-(

Comment: I tried that, but when I do that and try to navigate to the under div, it hides the under div completely. :(

Comment: ... well, on to the more complicated ways :-(, sorry